# How to apply a "composed" function on a list

Tags: r, function, lapply, function-composition

I would like to apply a "composed" function on all columns of a data frame.

For the example, sum(is.na). But:

```
lapply(data, sum(is.na))
```

returns an error.

Of course, one "simple" function does work, such as

```
lapply(data, is.na)
```

So, how can we apply "functions of functions"?

In particular, the composed function I have in mind is

```
plot(table)
```

with as many graphics generated as there are columns in the data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
lapply(data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
sapply(data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Comment: In this particular case `apply(is.na(df), 2, sum)` also works.